# template char/wchar_t, string/wstring, cout/wcout, regexp/wregex (or any possible workaround)

Tags: c++, string, templates, wstring, widestring

I'm dealing with `char` and `wchar_t`.

I'm writing a helper string class that puts on some regular expressions (with boost) to some strings, but I have both `string` and `wstring`. Now I have 2 functions with duplicated code for each functionality.

```
int countFoo(const char *s, const char *foo) {
    string text(s);

    boost::regex e(foo);

    int count = 0;
    boost::smatch match;
    while ( boost::regex_search( text, match, e ) ) {
        text = match.suffix();    
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int countFoo(const wchar_t *s, const wchar_t *foo) {
    wstring text(s);

    boost::wregex e(foo);

    int count = 0;
    boost::wsmatch match;
    while ( boost::regex_search( text, match, e ) ) {
        text = match.suffix();    
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It works, but I'm looking for some elegant method (template? some oop magic? function pointer?) to delete the duplicated code.

Comment: Normally one would pick a single encoding for the internals of a codebase. If data comes in or out in a different encoding, convert to and from the standard internal encoding at the boundary.

Comment: i have looked around but converting wstring in string seems a difficult task.. more than what i expected, anyway

Comment: It's not difficult and you only need to write the function once.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it as a template like this:

```
template <typename charT>
int countFoo(const charT *s, const charT *foo) {
    basic_string<char> text(s);

    boost::basic_regex<charT> e(foo);

    int count = 0;
    boost::match_results<typename basic_string<charT>::const_iterator> match;
    while ( boost::regex_search( text, match, e ) ) {
        text = match.suffix();    
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @David: `charT` is the template parameter. Corrected a mistake in the template declaration.

Comment: why not `std::basic_string<charT>`?